# javascript OR (||) not returning expected result

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I have a field that needs to accept input values for city/state in several formats, including `City ST` (Chicago IL), `City, ST` (Chicago, IL), and `City,ST` (Chicago,IL - no space between). We're testing for a two-letter state code after either a comma or the last instance of a space (because city names can have spaces.)

I have the following code that fails values that should pass, and vice versa.

```
var x = "Chicago,IL";
 if (
 (isNaN(x) && x.indexOf(' ') < 0 && x.split(" ").pop().length > 2) ||
 (isNaN(x) && x.indexOf(',') > 0 && x.split(",").pop().trim().length > 2)
 ) {
     alert("fail");
 }
else {
    alert("pass");
}
```

(Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ln9WE/))

So what my code SHOULD do is fail if 1) the value is not a number AND contains at least one space AND there are more than 2 characters after the final space, or 2) the value is not a number AND it contains a comma AND there are more than 2 characters after the comma (I'm trimming out a potential space after the comma.)

What's actually happening is, it's passing these values:

```
Chicago IL
Chicago, IL (with a space, even though it's trimming the space)
```

But failing `Chicago,IL` (entered initially without a space.) The reason I think it's a problem with the OR (`II`) is that if I remove the first part and test only for the value containing a comma, `Chicago,IL` passes. I thought that OR conditionals only return false if both sides of the OR are false, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

I'm sure this is a really simple thing, but I've been staring at it for way too long and just can't see it.

Comment: I think regex would be in order here.

Comment: Why are you performing this isNaN test here? assuming you're getting a value from a text field, it should always be a string

Comment: @jackweirdy But isNaN("1") still yields false. Maybe she just wants to discard numeric strings?

Comment: `x.indexOf(' ') < 0 && x.split(" ").pop().length > 2` doesn't make sense. If there is a space in the string, `x.indexOf(' ') < 0` is `false` and the the second expression won't be execute. If there isn't a space, `x.split(" ")` will return an array with one element, `x` itself. Do you mean `x.indexOf(' ') > 0` by any chance?

Comment: @LexLythius - yes, we're dealing with numeric strings in a different chunk, because the user can enter either a zip code or a city/state. We want to run this chunk of tests only if it's a city/state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems too complicated. If you are going to do it like that, *use multiple statements* (so that they can be reasoned about easier). Anyway, here is my "solution" which, admittedly, does not try to address why the original didn't work as expected:

```
var cityState = /^\w+(?:,\s*|\s+)\w{2}$/;
if (cityState.test(input)) {
    // good
}
```

---

To accept either "City Name, State" or "City Name State", consider this (more complex) regular expression. The key to this working is the lazy modifier and the anchoring.

```
function isValidState (st) {
  // This could be turned into an appropriate whitelist, and may include
  // things like "Illinois". 
  return st.length == 2;
}

function parseCityState (cs) {
  var match = cs.match(/^\s*(\w.*?)\s*([, ])\s*(\w+)\s*$/) || [];
  var city = match[1];
  var commaUsed = match[2] == ',';
  var state = match[3];
  if (city && state && isValidState(state)) {
    return {city: city, state: state, commaUse: commaUsed}
  } else {
    return undefined;
  }
}
```

---

Now, if you're interesting in why the original fails, consider this updated analysis for why "Chicago, IL" fails. Let `x = "Chicago, IL"`, then:

```
isNaN(x)       -> true
x.indexOf(' ') -> >0
x.indexOf(',') -> >0
x.split(' ')   -> ["Chicago,", "IL"]
x.split(',')   -> ["Chicago", " IL"]
```

And substituting:

```
true && (>0 < 0) && ["Chicago,", "IL"].pop().length > 2
||
true && (>0 > 0) && ["Chicago", " IL"].pop().trim().length > 2
```

Evaluation, again (note that the test for "no space" fails the first expression line because there *is* a space):

```
true && false && "IL".length > 2
||
true && true && "IL".length > 2
```

And evaluation again (note that both expression lines fail because "IL" only has a length of 2):

```
true && false && false
||
true && true && false
```

And ultimately this rejects the input:

```
false || false -> false
```

Comment: I agree with you that the way to go here would be RegExps, but I think the OP asks for something more essential about JS logic.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I would like to use your regex, but it doesn't account for possible spaces in city names. For example, Chicago IL passes, but Chicago Heights IL does not. Doesn't work if there's a comma, either (Chicago Heights, IL fails.) http://jsfiddle.net/edzYt/1

Comment: @user2246674 - I don't have a choice about how we're doing this; the client has provided very specific ways of handling states and zip codes.

Comment: @EmmyS I've updated the code with an example that uses a regular expression but can handle the more complex cases described. If more rules need to be handled that (for the sake of not making the regular expression unreadable), it might be useful to make a dispatch function that will call the correct "parser" depending on heuristics of what the input looks like. As a primitive example, the `isNaN` check can be part of the dispatcher - are we dealing with a ZIP code or something that looks like a City/State string? Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is true:

> I thought that OR conditionals only return false if both sides of the
>   OR are false

About this:

> if I remove the first part and test only for the value containing a comma, Chicago,IL passes

In your fiddler example, commenting out the first test prints "fail", which implies that it is evaluating to `true`.

There is no problem with JS ORs. But what is what you were expecting?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a mistake on this line
`x.indexOf(' ') < 0`
should be
`x.indexOf(' ') > 0`

---

But if I were you, I'd use a regular expression:

```
var info = 'South Beach, FL';
var regex = /\w+(\w+ \w+)*\s*,\s*[a-zA-Z]{2}/;

alert(regex.test(info) ? 'Valid' : 'Invalid')
```